# Bash run function multiple times at the same time

Tags: bash, loops

So I want to make a function (which can take some time to complete) run like 100 times at the same time. Using a for loop, it waits till the function is finished before it starts the other one. Here's a sample of what I mean:

```
sample() 
{ 
    echo "start"
    echo $1
    echo "end"
}

for (( i = 0; i <= 5; i++ )); do                                                     
    sample $i                                                                         
done
```

(yes this is bad code, it's just an example)
This will print 1 through 5 with start above it and end below it. It waits until the function is finished before it runs another one. How can I make it so it doesn't wait for the previous function in the loop to finish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `&` to run the function in background, and the `wait` command to wait for them all to finish.

```
for (( i = 0; i <= 5; i++ )); do                                                     
    sample $i &                                                                         
done   
wait
```